# How to calculate the velocity of a piston-like linkage?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, kinematics

I ve tried to solve this problem in so many ways but still didn't manage to do it...

[image]

What would be the correct way to solve it please?

This arm of this mechanism has a length of 0,2m. The piston has an angular velocity of 2000 tours/min. What would be the velocity of point D for an angle theta of 60 degrees?

I think that what I am missing is the angle formed by the arm and the line, which is 50mm long. Example like here (different 
exercise):

[image]

I am trying to look for this angle beta which could help me solve the problem

expected answer:2,88m/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you build a kinematic chain between *A*, *B* and *D* with radius $r$ between *AB* and the length $\ell$ between *BD*. The orientation angles from vertical are $\theta$ and $\phi$ respectively.

  1. $(x_B,y_B) = (x_A,y_A) + (-r \sin\theta,r \cos \theta)$
  2. $(x_D,y_D) = (x_B,y_B) + (-\ell \sin\phi, - \ell \cos \phi)$
- You find the angle $\phi$ from the constraint that $x_A-x_D = r \sin\theta + \ell \sin \phi = x_{AD}$ $$\sin \phi = \frac{x_{AD}}{\ell}-\frac{r}{\ell} \sin \theta $$
- Next you differentiate with respect to time using the chain rule to get the velocities

  1. $(\dot{x}_B,\dot{y}_B) = (-r \dot{\theta} \cos\theta, -r \dot{\theta}\sin\theta)$
  2. $(\dot{x}_D,\dot{y}_D) = (\dot{x}_B,\dot{y}_B) + (-\ell \dot{\phi} \cos\phi, \ell \dot{\phi} \sin \phi)$
- You find the rotational velocity of the connecting rod from the constraint $\dot{x}_D=-r\dot{\theta}\cos\theta -\ell \dot{\phi} \cos \phi=0$ $$ \dot{\phi} = - \frac{r \dot{\theta} \cos\theta}{\ell \cos{\phi}}$$
- The collar speed is

$$ v = \dot{y}_D = \ell \dot{\phi} \sin \phi - r \dot{\theta} \sin\theta = -\frac{r \sin(\theta+\phi)}{\cos\phi} \dot{\theta} $$ where $\dot{\theta}$ is the rotation of the disk in radians per second.

Answer (score 4):

The angle $\beta$ can be obtained from the geometry

$$ 0.2*1000 \sin (\beta )+50 \sin (60 {}^{\circ})=150 $$

This gives $\beta = 0.5627 rad$.

Assuming the angular velocity of the arm relative to B is $w$, the velocity of the point D can be computed as

$$ v_D=\frac{2000}{60} (2 \pi ) \{0,0,1\}\times \frac{50}{1000} \{-\sin (60
   {}^{\circ}),\cos (60 {}^{\circ}),0\}+\{0,0,w\}\times 0.2 \{-\sin (\beta
   ),-\cos (\beta ),0\}$$

$$ v_D= \{0.169161 w-5.23599,-0.106699 w-9.069,0.\}$$

The $x$ component of the velocity at D is zero, so setting the first element to zero we get $w = 30.9527 $. Substitute this in the second element to get the vertical velocity as $-12.3716$. It is moving downwards at 12.3716 m/s.